# How to show integrability

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to show that $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\left(\ln(1+\frac{1}{r})\right)^n(r+1)^nr}dr <\infty$ for $n>1$ but I am not sure how to proceed since the denominator tends to $0$ as $r$ tends to $0$. I have tried to use Holder's inequality and reduced it to the case where I need to show $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{(\ln(1+\frac{1}{r}))^{2n}r^{2n}} dr<\infty$ but I'm not sure that this will help. I also thought to just integrate on $[\epsilon, 1]$ for $\epsilon$ small and take a limit but I'm having issues getting an upper bound that does not depend on $\epsilon$. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the substitution $e^x-1=\frac{1}{r}$ to see for any $b\in(0,1)$ that $$\int_b^1\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\Big(\ln\big(1+\frac{1}{r}\big)\Big)^n(r+1)^nr}=\int_{\ln(2)}^{\ln\big(1+\frac{1}{b}\big)}\Big(\frac{e^x-1}{e^x}\Big)^{n-1}\frac{1}{x^n}\mathrm{d}x$$ Since $\Big(\frac{e^x-1}{e^x}\Big)^{n-1}\rightarrow 1$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$ we see from the limit comparison test $\lim_{b \rightarrow 0^+}\int_{\ln(2)}^{\ln\big(1+\frac{1}{b}\big)}\Big(\frac{e^x-1}{e^x}\Big)^{n-1}\frac{1}{x^n}\mathrm{d}x$ exists if and only if $\lim_{b\rightarrow \infty}\int_{\ln(2)}^{b}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^n}$ exists if and only if $n>1$.